# how to do complex criteria for =COUNTIF()

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumifs

How to do this on excel: `=COUNTIF(D5:D13;D5:D13<F5:F13)`

I tried

```
=COUNTIF(D5:D13;D5:D13<F5:F13)
```

and it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(D5:D13<F5:F13))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but the fact is that I would write it into a "COUNTIF" condition because I want to do the comparaison on the rows which meet others conditions : =COUNTIFS(D4:D10;"<"&H4:H10;E4:E10;"<"&10) for example.

Comment: You can use multiple criteria with sumproduct joining it with * . In that case it would be =SUMPRODUCT(--((D4:D10<H4:H10)*(E4:E10<10)))

Answer (score 1):

I would use countifs() like so:

[image]

Less typing! I can't type well :)

Still looking at this...

Comment: This is what I get when I use your formula : [image](https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=23/08/0ke4.png).

Comment: @OwenSgbd Use correct syntax formula & check. COUNTIFS(X42:X47,"<"&Y42:Y47). You have used **";"** instead of **","** in countifs formula.

Comment: I used the syntax you mentionned and here is what I get : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=23/09/10jy.png